# default.xml showing error "Cannot resolve symbol 'string'" in PHP Storm IDE

Tags: magento2, xml, phpstorm

default.xml showing error "Cannot resolve symbol 'string'" in PHP Storm IDE, but it's not effecting anything. Is this ok? Or is there something wrong?

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the first line phpStorm does not know the XSD schemas.

You can either add this manually (open settings and search for `DTS`) or run:

```
bin/magento dev:urn-catalog:generate .idea/misc.xml
```

<sup>Ref.: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-urn.html</sup>

Answer (score 0):

## Open   PhpStorm

you need to install "plugin PhpStorm Magento 2 Plugin"

- FILE > Settings > Plugins >
- click on the tab"Marketplace"
- in the search type: "Magento PhpStorm"

then install it and restart phpStorm.

now most errors will be solved.